# Filter query by count associated data CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, counting, cakephp-3.x, aggregates

I want to do a query on “Articles” but I only want the “Articles” which have two or more “Comments”. So I have to count “Comments” and use the count result in the where clause.

I know the next code is wrong but it would be something like:

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find();

$articles->matching('Comments', function ($q) {
    $commentsCount = $q->func()->count('Comments.id');   
    return $q->where($commentsCount . ' >= ' => 2);
});
```

I can´t find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to first figure out how you'd do it in raw SQL, that will make it way easier to figure how to replicate it with CakePHP's query builder.

For example, you cannot use an aggregate in the `WHERE` clause, that's forbidden in all supported DBMS. `WHERE` is evaluated *before* grouping is applied (ie before anything can be counted), you'd have to check the aggregate in the `HAVING` clause instead, which is evaluated *after* grouping.

Usually you'd do something along the lines of this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    Articles.id, ...
FROM
    articles Articles
LEFT JOIN
    comments Comments ON Comments.article_id = Articles.id
GROUP BY
    Articles.id
HAVING
    COUNT(Comments.id) >= 2
```

This can be easily achieved with the query builder like this:

```php
$query = $this->Articles
    ->find()
    ->leftJoinWith('Comments')
    ->group('Articles.id')
    ->having(function (
        \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
        \Cake\ORM\Query $query
    ) {
        return $exp->gte(
            $query->func()->count('Comments.id'),
            2,
            'integer'
        );
    });
```

Such a query can be very expensive on large tables, as it cannot use any indices, and thus requires a full table scan, ie it has to check every single row. One way to avoid that is using counter caching, which stores the number of associated records in the source table, that way you can compare against an indexable column in the `Articles` table, ie you could then simply do:

```php
$query = $this->Articles
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'Articles.comment_count >=' => 2,
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data > Aggregates - Group and Having](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Behaviors > CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)**